# Opera Turbo and proxy

Tags: browser, proxy, opera

[Opera Turbo](http://www.opera.com/turbo)
There, they says:

### How does it work?

> When you enable Opera Turbo, the pages you request are passed through
> one of Opera's data-saving servers. The server removes any extraneous
> page elements, shaves off image pixels you won't miss, diagnoses the
> state of your connection and compresses downloads. This smart,
> cloud-based technology does all this before sending the page to your
> device.

Does that mean that Opera's servers act as a proxy between the user and the website he is accessing?
From their explanation, I think that the Opera server will fetch the webpages and send them to the user, so the user's details(such as IP Address, browser version, Windows version etc...) wouldn't be logged there. It is only my assumption and please correct me if I am wrong about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean that Opera's servers act as a proxy between the user and the website he is accessing?

Yes.

> From their explanation, I think that the Opera server will fetch the webpages and send them to the user

Thart's pretty much how proxies work.

> so the user's details(such as IP Address, browser version, Windows version etc...) wouldn't be logged there. It is only my assumption and please correct me if I am wrong about it.

They may or may not log your details, regardless of what they claim.  Sadly, you have no way to tell one way or the other.

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?  Thank you.

Comment: Incidentally,  because Opera creates a vpn ,  it's a handy way of bypassing sites blocked by your service provider.  ;)

Comment: @DavidWilson Just keep in mind [who owns Opera](http://techcrunch.com/2016/02/25/opera-ceo-sale-to-chinese-consortium-wasnt-our-decision/) these days. :)